# What are all the names from Arrow's kill list and what is the status of these people?

Tags: arrowverse, arrow

The main theme of Arrow season 1 was Oliver's kill list,

[image]

He used to kill those persons on the list and then strike down their names:

[image]

But later he grows from a vigilante to a hero and he left using it. We see the list again in season 5 during the Russia flashback but we never see the whole list together and even Oliver's list was incomplete, because he burned a few pages but got his mom's list later on.

So my question is, what is the full list of names in the notebook and what is their status now?

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2461/49).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Arrowverse Wiki has [a comprehensive article](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/The_List) of all 65 people known to be on The List. Given its length, I won't repeat it here. However, I'll call out a few notable people as of this writing

### Only 4 out of the 24 who have appeared are walking free

At the time of this writing, there are 24 people who are on The List who have appeared on the show or tie-in comics. All of them are dead or incarcerated except for the following:

- [Monty Cora](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Monty_Cora) (Deathride): Only appeared in the tie-in comics. A hitman for hire and reigning champion at the Tournament of Skulls. Oliver fought him, but did not kill him.
- [Doug Miller](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Doug_Miller): Head of Applied Sciences for Palmer Technologies. In 1x09 "[Year's End](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Year%27s_End)", Walter Steele read his name on the copy of The List that he got from Moira Queen. He called Miller, but he feigned ignorance, then told Malcolm Merlyn that Walter knew about the list. Miller has not been seen since, and never encountered Oliver Queen. Note that in one flashback, Oliver ripped out a few pages from his father's notebook (before he knew what it was) to start a fire. It's possible that this name was only on Moira Queen's copy and not the one that Oliver had.
- [Marcus Redmond](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Marcus_Redmond): In the episode 1x02 "[Honor Thy Father](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Honor_Thy_Father)", Oliver threatened his life telling him to return the $30 million embezzled from the Halcyon pension plan. After he did so, Oliver did not encounter him again
- [Ken Williams](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Ken_Williams): In 1x15 "[Dodger](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Dodger)", Oliver was planning on going after him because he stole millions through a pyramid scheme. After Felicity convinced him to stop because the man was a single father, Oliver warned Williams and he returned all the money. Note that Williams never actually appeared on screen.

Although he died, I'd also like to draw attention to [Hannibal Bates](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Hannibal_Bates). He was on The List (you can clearly see his name in the second picture in the question), but he made his only appearance on *The Flash* where he was a shapeshifting metahuman who was later killed by Eobard Thawne. Bates is currently the only person to be on The List that has been on another Arrowverse show.

### There are 39 remaining names on The List who have not appeared

Some of these people are probably never going to appear. For instance, Deadshot tattoos the names of his targets on his chest (as he did with [James Holder](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/James_Holder)). Since Deadshot had tattooed the names [Wes Anselm](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Wes_Anselm) and [Yasemin Soze](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Yasemin_Soze), both of whom were on The List, it appears that he killed them before Oliver got a chance to go after them.

However, it is possible that some of the remaining people on The List may still appear. Way back in the pilot, [Danny Brickwell](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Danny_Brickwell) was shown to be on The List (again, the second picture in the question clearly shows his name), but he didn't appear in the flesh until 56 episodes later in 3x10 "[Left Behind](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Left_Behind_(Arrow))" at which point he became a recurring villain. Similarly, [Joseph Cray](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Joseph_Cray) appeared in 3x17 "[Suicidal Tendencies](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Suicidal_Tendencies)", although that was his only appearance. It's certainly possible that more names may appear.